# Rails Starting Up With Wrong Version of Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, ruby-1.9.2

**TLDR: How do I force a rails app to use the correct ruby interpreter?**

Hello,

Something hosed parts of my Ruby 1.9.2p290 install (certain classes just went missing one day), so I removed it and attempted to reinstall the environment.

I'm running on Snow Leopard.

Ruby 1.9.2 was installed from source. (I tried to install via MacPorts and it would fail). I am not keen on RVM as I use bundler and I seem to recall some problems with how bundler and RVM interact, though from what I can tell RVM works.

After reinstalling a few gems I noticed they were being placed in a gem folder for Ruby 1.8. "This is weird," I thought.

Starting up the rails app, I notice a lot of weird exceptions being thrown regarding syntax. After printing RUBY_VERSION to stdout, I noticed that the Rails app is running 1.8.7.

`which ruby` shows only one ruby interpreter:

```
$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
$ /usr/bin/ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
```

If I open up Activity Monitor, the ruby process from the Rails app lives at `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby`, which I believe is the ruby interpreter that OSX shipped with.

I haven't found any information on completely purging Ruby from OSX. I would love to do that then simply install ruby from source.

It seems there are two problems:

- Rails is running a ruby interpreter that I have no idea how it is calling, when I need it to run the 1.9.2 interpreter installed from source
- gems are being installed in a 1.8 folder, I suspect because gem thinks its running under 1.8

How do I fix this?

Thank you,

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the best way to overcome this issue is using rvm to handle your Ruby and Rails environments through 'gemset's.

I had the same issue and I use gemsets now without a problem.

This is the article which I got things working:

http://stjhimy.com/posts/10-five-quick-steps-to-set-up-rvm-with-rails-2-and-rails3